# jquery ajax problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my post.php I use $.ajax function to load some html data from other file lets call it form.html. My question is is it possible form.html to access post.php POST/GET data when is added to the DOM of post.php ?

Comment: On page load, or when user clicks something?

Comment: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: In  post.php I make some form validations. If something is wrong post.php is reloaded again with $_POST data containing data for re-populating fields. Those fields are in form.php which is called via ajax

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use $.ajax to post to a php file, which returns html data. this way you can fill in your posted data in the html.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with what you are trying to do. But regardless you can still access the 
$_POST[] data from any DOM element on page load.